# Mendeley does not write correctly bibliography

Tags: bibliography, citations, mendeley, csl

Let's assume I have got correct .RIS and/or .bib files imported into Mendeley.

When I create the Mendeley Bibliography in a Office Word file articles with many authors are not written correctly by Mendeley with Geophysical Research Letters style.

E.g. see the following pic (note article chosen randomly):

[image]

The article above has 13 authors in total but Mendeley only displays 7 of them with also `...` as gap between the 6th and 13th author.

I need all authors shown in my bibliography as per Geophysical Research Letters' style.

How can I solve this?

Any help would be really appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this has multiple parts:

1. Note that the AGU, which publishes GRL, has recently changed its citation format to APA style as described here: https://eos.org/editors-vox/new-style-for-agu-journals-and-books What you have pasted above is an APA-style citation.
2. using et al. for 8 or more authors is correct in the new style
3. *However*, the elipsis between the 6th and the last author is not supposed to be there, a deviation from APA rules by the AGU style. [I have just fixed this](https://github.com/citation-style-language/styles/commit/3ba8c6adb7cb7202b112c1aa37f10cf03f01ab21) in the upstream repository from which Mendeley draws its styles and it should be available for updating within 48hs in Mendeley. The style that actually updates, btw., is American Geophysical Union, all their journals (such as GRL) just point to that style
4. If you do want to edit et al settings in a CSL style by yourself for used in Mendeley, the easiest way is probably [Mendeley's CSL Editor](https://www.mendeley.com/guides/csl-editor). There, you would click on "Bibliography" on the left and adjust the et al settings. There are three of relevance:

   - `et-al-min` which determines the number of authors at which et al kicks in. E.g., it's set to 8 for AGU which means "start using et al for 8 or more authors".
   - `et-al-use-first` which determines how many authors are listed before et al. (currently 6 for AGU)
   - `et-al-use-last` which determines whether elipsis are used as described above. This can only be true or false.

Comment: hi, thanks. I did point 4. but I could not be able to save the csl file into my Mendeley Desktop. error: Cannot install - http://csl.mendeley.com/styles/484920821/american-geophysical-union-2. Error: Cannot connect to the server. ...that's really annoying honestly...what's the point in updating a journal style if it is not correct?

Comment: Sorry, I can't help with getting the custom style into Mendeley, that sounds like a bug on their end. The second part I don't understand -- the style that's correct as per AGU guidelines should now be available for Mendeley.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem and besides changing the Bibliography section, I changed the Global Formatting section and it worked well